# Как избавиться от ошибки PCIe bus error в Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, железо, install, msi

Купил MSI GP62M 7RDX Leopard и поставил туда Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-бит. Запускать ОС пришлось с параметром nomodeset, так как без него даже liveCD не грузился. Установив драйвера nVidia последней версии, ОС стала запускаться нормальнно и без параметра nomodeset,но при нажатии ctrl+alt+f1 появляются ошибки:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsN3a.jpg

```
lspci -nnk

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a110] (rev f1)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:a113] (rev f1)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
```

Первое устройство выдает эти ошибки. Не могу понять с чем это связано и как это починить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В /etc/default/grub в строке GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT прописать "pci=nommconf"
Как прописано у меня:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nommconf quiet splash"